# Some animation css effect makes div smaller

Tags: html, css

My jsfiddle is here : https://jsfiddle.net/yak8h1rf/1/

Css code :

```
.animaEmerge {
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-animation-name: emerge;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-name: emerge;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes emerge {
  from {
    background-color: lightskyblue;
  }
  to {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

@keyframes emerge {
  from {
    background-color: lightskyblue;
  }
  to {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

My problem is that in my browser, (Chrome 59.0.3071.115)

This shows like this

[image]

That is so ugly, Why in jsfiddle, it's okay but in browser, it's crashed?

How can i fix it like in jsfiddle,

I want to make it do not change it's width.

Comment: How do you want it to display?

Comment: @ArunCM I want it to be unchanged with any animation. Like in jsfiddle, i want unchanging width.

Comment: Let me know your feedback. I have posted an answer, please verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether I understood your question correctly. If you want to set the div width to full size to container, change 
`<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12">` 
to
`<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12" style="width:100%">`

Here is the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yak8h1rf/2/)

```css
.animaEmerge {
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-animation-name: emerge;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-name: emerge;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes emerge {
  from {
    background-color: lightskyblue;
  }
  to {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

@keyframes emerge {
  from {
    background-color: lightskyblue;
  }
  to {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid" id="contentsbox">

  <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px;">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12" style="width:100%">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-left animaEmerge" style="background-color: transparent; font-size:14px; color:black; border-width : 1px; border-color:#c4dce8; border-style: solid; height: auto;">
          <p>Here will be smaller</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-right" style="background-color: #c4dce8; font-size:14px; color: #999999; height: auto;">
          <p>It's okay without .animaEmerge</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ArunCM